# How to store multiple lines of input in array and type them using keyboard.type, keyboard.press, and keyboard.enter functions?

Tags: python

I have made this code but this types only the "stop" word. If I initialize the arr by putting a few strings in it, for example:

```
arr=["hello","world"]
```

only the first string (hello) is typed

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key,Controller
import time
keyboard = Controller()

print("Menu: ")
print("Enter 1 to manually type the message to be spammed")
print("Enter any other value to end the program")
choice=int(input("Enter your choice: "))
arr=[]
message=""
a=0 
if choice==1:
    while True:
    message = input("Enter Text: ")
    if message == 'stop': 
        break
    arr.append(message)
    a=a+1
else:
    print("Thank You for using the program")
    exit()

print("Please take the cursor where you want to spam the message, spamming will start in 5 seconds...")

time.sleep(5)


if choice==1:
    for num in range(a):
        for idx, item in enumerate(arr):
            keyboard.type(item)
            keyboard.press(Key.Enter)
            keyboard.release(Key.Enter)
            idx=idx+1
            time.sleep(0.05)
   
        num=num+1
        if num>1000:
            time.sleep(0.2)
```

I am not sure if the variable named arr is a list or dynamic array or whatever, I am new to Python but have learned C++ earlier and names anyway don't matter.

The aim of this program is to allow the user to type multiple strings in the terminal and let the program type the same strings for him (in different lines). I think it is helpful because user can just copy a few lines from anywhere and paste them in the terminal. Now, the program should type the same lines for him, but now, the lines will be sent as separate messages instead of one big message.